# Change the color of an instantiated prefab Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer

so the player hits a button to create a box. I need this box to be randomly varying between a few colors. I also need this box to have a tag corresponding to said color. Green box - "greenBlock" tag etc.

I have instantiated the box and then try to change it's material with material.color. It doesn't do anything. I've seen suggestions of sharedMaterial but having tried that found it just ends up changing the color of every game object in the scene. I think I'm fetching the box prefabs renderer correctly? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Box;
    public Transform spawnpoint1;
    public Transform spawnpoint2;
    public Rigidbody2D player;
    public Renderer boxRenderer;

    [SerializeField]
    private Color boxColor;
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource actionSound;

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Start()
    {
        //boxRenderer = Box.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        boxRenderer = GameObject.Find("Box").GetComponent<Renderer>();  //  Find the renderer of the box prefab
    }


    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (player) //  If it's the player in the collider trigger
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Instantiate(Box, spawnpoint1.position, Quaternion.identity);
                boxRenderer.material.color = boxColor;  //  change the color after it is instantiated
                actionSound.Play();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boxRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", boxColor);
```

or

```
boxRenderer.material.color = new Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And when you instantiate the box, you need to get the render for the box at this point as it is a new object. So:

```
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Box = Instantiate(Box, spawnpoint1.position, Quaternion.identity);
            boxRenderer = Box.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            boxRenderer.material.color = boxColor;  //  change the color after it is instantiated
            actionSound.Play();
        }
```

Note you have creating a New color and assigning it, you can't modify the color there as it may be used on other objects that are using the same material.

Check out `SetColor` in the docs, that is setting the shader property called `_Color` which is the default color element in shaders, you can of course have more depending on the shader.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So i switched it to material.SetColor but it hasn't changed it. Am I getting a reference to the instantiated game object's renderer correctly? It's a prefab if that makes any difference.

Comment: Oh yah, that won't work. You are instantiating the box, you need to get the renderer for the box you instantiated as it is new. I'll update my code in the answer.

Comment: So now there's no errors but the boxes are invisible!

Comment: It's exactly the same as what's here except I've got Gavin's if statement. I'm pretty sure I'm calling the renderer component of the box prefab incorrectly..?

For the gameobject.find() method should the string be 'Box' as that's what i declared it to be locally or should it be the name of the prefab that I'm giving it?

Comment: I assume you are setting the value of `boxColor` somewhere? Its default is (0,0,0,0) based on the code above and therefore transparent

Comment: Yikes. Had set it in the inspector to be red but had the alpha at 0. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Neilk `boxrenderer` is being used like a local variable, but is declared at class level. You should remove the declaration from the class and keep it local.